# I am adding dll in web application but that dll cannot access the class names what is the problem?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-assembly

I am using a dll(NEWDAO.dll) in web application. It has a cs file, I can access that class name in web application but it is not came what is the problem, pls give me any suggestion

in NEWDAO name space class is DBConnection code is

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
namespace NEWDAO
{
    class DbConnection
    {
        private int _EmpName;
        private string _Name;
        private decimal _Salary;
        private DateTime _CreatedDate;
        public bool Flag = false;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlConnection m_Con = new SqlConnection("Server=*******,dataSource=Test,user name=sa,password=*******");
        SqlCommand m_Cmd = new SqlCommand();

        public int EmpNo
        {
            get
            {
                return _EmpName;
            }
            set
            {
                _EmpName = value;
            }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _Name;
            }
            set
            {
                _Name = value;
            }
        }

        public decimal Salary
        {
            get
            {
                return _Salary;
            }
            set
            {
                _Salary = value;
            }
        }

        public DateTime CreatedDate
        {
            get
            {
                return _CreatedDate;
            }
            set
            {
                _CreatedDate = value;
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Insert the Emp values
        /// </summary>
        public bool EmpInsert()
        {
            Flag = false;
            m_Con.Open();
            SqlCommand m_Cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_EmpInsert", m_Con);
            m_Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            m_Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpName", EmpNo);
            m_Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);
            m_Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Salary", Salary);
            m_Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedDate", CreatedDate);
            if (m_Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() >= 0)
            {
                Flag = true;
                return Flag;

            }
            else
            {
                return Flag;
            }
            m_Con.Close();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Display the values
        /// </summary>
        public bool EmpSelect(out DataSet oDS)
        {
            Flag = false;
            m_Con.Open();
            SqlCommand m_Cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_EmpInsert", m_Con);
            m_Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("usp_EmpInsert", m_Con);
            ad.Fill(ds, "EMP");
            if (ds != null)
            {
                oDS = ds;
                Flag = true;
                return Flag;
            }
            else
            {
                oDS = null;
                return Flag;
            }
            m_Con.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

thank you
hemanth

Comment: how did you add this dll to your web application?

Comment: Are you sure that the class you are trying to use is public?

Comment: add reference browse select the dll after add the .aspx.cs file using DAO also

Comment: well as you see there is no public keyword against the `DbConnection` class and the namespace is also `NEWDAO` and not `DAO`

Comment: Everything you posted is standard .NET, so your not using anything from the dll class at this point, do you mean to do this?  All your doing right now is placing your class inside the same namespace in theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class should be [public](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzh058ae.aspx) to access from another assembly. [Internal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx) is the default if no access modifier is specified.

- Set the class as public (`public class DbConnection`)
- Add reference to your dll

you can access this class as bellow

```
NEWDAO.DbConnection
```

Or you can [add a using directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (`using NEWDAO;`) and access `DbConnection` directly

Answer (score 2):

You should also check to see if your class is public. The default access modifier is internal.

Comment: unless you specify an access modifier like public, private etc... your class will have the "internal" access modifier by default, which will prevent you from seing your class from a different assembly

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `using` directive that has the namespace where this class exists in, or use the full name, including the namespace.

So, if the full class name is:

```
DAO.SourceWordDoc
```

Either add a:

```
using DAO;
```

Or use the full name - `DAO.SourceWordDoc`.

Comment: @hmkmudiam - Are you sure that is the correct namespace? How have you added the reference? What namespace is the class in?

Comment: name space is DAO and class name is DbConnection

Comment: @hmkmudiam - And the class is public? Can you please add the code you are trying to the question?

Comment: @hmkmudiam - And the class that uses that code? How have you added the reference to the project?

Comment: sorry sir previous code is another project now u can see the code it is correct  after i can add using NEWDAO

Comment: sir pls tel me what is the problem

Comment: @hmkmudiam - Your question is not clear.  As I already explained in my above comment, you have not imported the namespace which contains the class you want to use, not that it matters since you never even attempt to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your application is targeting a different target framework than the assemblie.
E.g. for a WPF Project, check

Properties -> Application -> Target Framework

Possible your DLL requires the full framework and your app is only targeting the client profile.